# Double "Home" tab on terminal when i open it

Tags: pantheon-terminal, release-hera, bugs

[image]
Every time i open a new terminal, it open with 2 tabs, its so annoying and i dont know how i resolve this.

I ask in a eOS group on telegram but nobody its able to help me and some people have this problem too..

Anyone can save me ?
(i'm using eOS Hera 5.1)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with terminal (https://github.com/elementary/terminal/issues/444) there is a pull request that claims to fix this so hopefully if that gets merged the next update can correct the behaviour.